# Plotly not handling NA's well for Bar charts. Where shall I address that?

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, holoviews

I want to create a bar-chart with the plotly backend. I use the `aggregate`-function to count the number of items in each category. Let me show an example.
First I create some test-data:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('plotly')
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
samples = 100

pets = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Hamster', 'Rabbit']
genders = ['Female', 'Male']

pets_sample = np.random.choice(pets, samples)
gender_sample = np.random.choice(genders, samples)
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'pet':pets_sample,'gender':gender_sample,})
df['pet']=pd.Categorical(df['pet'])
df['gender']=pd.Categorical(df['gender'])
# Delete male hamsters so we have an empty category-combination
df=df[~((df['pet']=='Hamster') & (df['gender']=='Male'))]
df['name']=['Animal #'+str(i) for i in range(len(df))]
df=df[['name','pet','gender']]
df
```

[image: dataframe]

When I try to plot this, using

```
bars = hv.Bars(df, kdims=['pet', 'gender'],vdims='name').aggregate(function=np.count_nonzero)

bars.opts(width=1000,multi_level=False)
```

I get the following error: `ValueError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant`.

The reason for that is (I think) that there is one NA in the aggregated table:

```
hv.Table(df, kdims=['pet', 'gender'],vdims='name').aggregate(function=np.count_nonzero)
```

returns

[image: Aggregated table]

You can solve this problem by adding a new column to the dataframe, just consisting of ones and use `np.sum` instead of `np.count_nonzero` and then everything works:

```
df['ones']=1
bars=hv.Bars(df, kdims=['pet', 'gender'],vdims=[('ones','count')]).aggregate(function=np.sum)
bars.opts(width=1000,multi_level=False)
```

[image: bar-chart]

I think NA's should default to zero when making Bar-charts. My original approach works fine if I use `bokeh` as backend.
I would like to know where would be a good place to address this issue. The github of holoviews of plotly?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I looked into the traceback and this seems to be an issue of `bokeh`, because

1. `holoviews` uses
2. `panel` which calls
3. `bokeh` to generates a `json` which
4. should be rendered with `plotly`

In this process somewhere this line is called inside `bokeh`,

```
json.dumps(
    obj,
    cls=BokehJSONEncoder,
    allow_nan=False,
    indent=indent,
    separators=separators,
    sort_keys=True,
    **kwargs
)
```

where `allow_nan` is set to `False`.

I quote from the documentation of the `bokeh` [`BokehJSONEncoder`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/json_encoder.html?highlight=bokehjsonencoder#bokeh.core.json_encoder.BokehJSONEncoder)

> If `allow_nan` is true (default), then NaN, Infinity, and -Infinity will be encoded as such. This behavior is not JSON specification compliant, but is consistent with most JavaScript based encoders and decoders. Otherwise, it will be a ValueError to encode such floats.

because this is the class used by the python [`json` bulid-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage).

I do not know the reason why this is deactivated, but it looks like it is on purpose, beacuse this can not be set.

I think because it is hard to get a overview about this topic and all the relationships, you should address you problem in the [`holoviz`](https://discourse.holoviz.org/) forum. This seems to be the place where all the experts are.

An alternative could also be the [`bokeh`](https://discourse.bokeh.org/) forum.

Comment: Yes, either the bokeh or holoviz forum is a good idea; this falls into a bit of a gray area between them. The Bokeh developers are well aware of this issue, but it could also be to do with how Panel is using Bokeh.